# Characteristics for nonlinear waves governed by $u_t + c(u)u_x = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I have some confuse about the characteristic of nonlinear wave propagation. I read the PDF from A. Salih at IIST about the Inviscid Burgers’ Equation, where the original PDF can be find at the (https://www.iist.ac.in/sites/default/files/people/IN08026/Burgers_equation_inviscid.pdf)

So, I am not fully understand some statement about the characteristic line in this PDF.

Consider the 1D nonlinear advection equation
$$ u_t + c(u)u_x = 0$$
where the wave speed is not constant but a nonlinear term $c(u)$.

As above PDF state, we defined the characteristic curve as
$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = c(u).$$
Then Let $x = x(t)$, we have
$$\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t),t) = \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt} = u_t +c(u)u_x = 0$$
Therefore the $u$ is constant long the characteristic curve, and the characteristic curve is straight line since
$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}(\frac{dx}{dt}) = \frac{dc(u)}{dt} = c'(u)\frac{du}{dt} = 0$$

I didn't understand 3 places,

(1) why we can just assume the $x$ is dependence of $t$.

(2) why we say the $u$ is constant long the characteristic curve. For sure, the $\frac{d}{dt}u(x(t),t) = 0$ shows that the solution $u$ does not change along time, but I don't understand what logic shows that the $u$ is constant along $ \frac{dx}{dt} = c(u)$.

(3) why the characteristic curve is straight line because
$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} =  c'(u)\frac{du}{dt} = 0$. How do I know the derivative of $c(u)$ is equal to zero?

Could someone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is some confusion with the derivation's steps and notation, which OP presents in the wrong logical order. Below, the proper way is shown (see also [this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3225996/418542)).

First things first, we write the initial-value problem for the quasi-linear conservation law
$$
u_t + c(u) u_x =0 , \qquad u(x,0) = \phi(x).
$$
The dependent variables are position $x$ and time $t$, and the unknown is $u(x,t)$.
The method of characteristics consists in seeking a parametrisation $s \mapsto \big(x(s),t(s),u(s)\big)$
of these quantities, in such a way that the PDE transforms into ordinary differential equations which we might be able to solve. Note in passing that the dependence of $u$ w.r.t. $s$ can be expressed as $u = u(x(s), t(s))$, and similar notation can be used for the partial derivatives. Using the chain rule, the evolution of $u$ is governed by
\begin{aligned}
\frac{d}{ds}u(s) &= x'(s) u_x(s) + t'(s) u_t(s) \\
&= \left[x'(s) - c(u(s))t'(s)\right] u_x(s)
\end{aligned}
where we have used the PDE.
As shown in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics), we may write the system
$$
\frac{dt}{ds} = 1, \quad \frac{dx}{ds} = c(u), \quad \frac{du}{ds} = 0 
$$
with initial condition $t(0) = 0$, $x(0) = x_0$ and $u(0) = \phi(x_0)$, which resolution can be tackled by hand. Here, we find
$$
t=s, \quad x = x_0 + c(\phi(x_0))\, s,\quad u = \phi(x_0).
$$

Now let us go back to OP's questions. Given that $t=s$, this can be rewritten as
$$
x = x_0 + c(\phi(x_0))\, t,\quad u = \phi(x_0),
$$
as a consequence of the choice $x' = c(u)$ with $u'=0$. Now, we can express the unknown as $u = u(x(t), t)$, and similar notation can be used for the partial derivatives.
We note that $u = \phi(x_0)$ is constant along the characteristic curve $t \mapsto x(t)$ starting at $(x_0, 0)$, and that those curves are straight lines in the $x$-$t$ plane. In fact, computation of the derivative of $u$ along those lines gives
$$
\frac{d}{dt}u(t) = x'(t) u_x(t) + u_t(t) = 0
$$
according to the definition of the characteristic curves and the PDE itself. Since the slope $x' = c(u)$ of these lines is a function of $u$ with $u$ constant, we can conclude that $x'$ is constant too.